# How does Perl split work with string exactly?

Tags: perl

Quoted from `perldoc -f split`:

> As a special case, specifying a PATTERN of space (' ' ) will split on
>   white space just as split with no arguments does. Thus, split(' ') can
>   be used to emulate awk's default behavior, whereas split(/ /) will
>   give you as many initial null fields (empty string) as there are
>   leading spaces.

The above is all that's mentioned about how split deals with `string` delimiter, but what's the general case,is the empty leading fields always deleted for string delimiters?

Comment: The behavior of `split` with a string for a PATTERN, other than `' '`, is not specified.  `split` is mostly meant to be used with a regexp...

Comment: @Nemo: it is specified: `The pattern "/PATTERN/" may be replaced with an expression to specify patterns that vary at runtime.`, a string being one case of an expression.

Comment: you can also split on whitespace via `/\s+/` without the special behaviour of `' '`. this will group multiple space characters into one field separator

Answer (score 2):

No, only when the delimiter is a string that is a single space.  In any other case, the delimiter is interpreted as a regex pattern.

Comment: So one CAN'T make `split` to delete the empty leading fields if the delimiter is not a single space?

Comment: It would be trivial to trim the string yourself with a regex before doing the split though, or throw away the leading undef results of the array.

Comment: @Justin Hawkins, and there would be a most one such empty string. `shift(@results) if @results && $results[0] eq '';`